# Add subtitle to annotation using UICRouteAnnotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dictionary

```
UICRouteAnnotation *startAnnotation = [[UICRouteAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate [[routePoints objectAtIndex:0] coordinate]
title:@"Origin"
subtitle:@"Subtitle Here"
annotationType:UICRouteAnnotationTypeStart];
```

I am trying to add a subtitle to this annotation but don't have much experience with UICRouteAnnotation and was not able to find much documentation on it. Adding "subtitle:" through exceptions.

What am I missing? Why doesn't the subtitle work when doing it like this?

Comment: Do you mean "Adding subtitle: throws exceptions"?  What exceptions exactly?  Does the subtitle parameter actually exist in the initWithCoordinate method of UICRouteAnnotation?

Comment: I don't believe it does but I'm not sure how to rewrite it. I get this warning... warning: Semantic Issue: Instance method '-initWithCoordinate:title:subtitle:annotationType:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: Can you post the UICRouteAnnotation.h and .m files?

Comment: Just by asking that question you made me realize what I needed to do. Sorry... I wasn't thinking clearly. I just needed to add the subtitle attributes to the UICRouteAnnotation.h and .m files and it's working great. Thanks!

Comment: Great, you can post your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

What I didn't realize is that UICRouteAnnotation needed to be modified to accept a subtitle. Here is my updated h and m files for UICRouteAnnotation. Making the below changes fixed my issue so the code I posted in my question works as intended.

Thanks Anna for pointing me in the right direction.

.h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

typedef enum UICRouteAnnotationType {
    UICRouteAnnotationTypeStart,
    UICRouteAnnotationTypeEnd,
    UICRouteAnnotationTypeWayPoint,
} UICRouteAnnotationType;

@interface UICRouteAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
    NSString *title;
    NSString *subtitle;
    UICRouteAnnotationType annotationType;
}

@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic) UICRouteAnnotationType annotationType;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord 
                   title:(NSString *)aTitle 
                   subtitle:(NSString *)aSubTitle 
          annotationType:(UICRouteAnnotationType)type;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "UICRouteAnnotation.h"

@implementation UICRouteAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize subtitle;
@synthesize annotationType;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord 
                   title:(NSString *)aTitle 
                subtitle:(NSString *)aSubTitle
          annotationType:(UICRouteAnnotationType)type {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        coordinate = coord;
        title = [aTitle retain];
        subtitle = [aSubTitle retain];
        annotationType = type;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I'd just add `@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;` and especially `[subtitle release];` in `dealloc`.